# Java: copy files between directories

Tags: java, file, directory

Using java how can I move a file from one directory to another? Should I just use streamReader to copy the bytes over to the destination directory then delete the original file?

Comment: check this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/MovingFile.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`File.renameTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) operation. Despite its name, it may also be used to move files around. However, be warned, that, as the documentation states, that its behaviour will depend on the platform you are running on.

Example:

```
File oldFile = ...;
File newDirectory = ...;
String newName = ...;
File newFile = new File(newDirectory, newName);

oldName.renameTo(newFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

That sounds wrong. If you're indeed *moving* the file (and not making a copy), then you should be using the much cheaper rename method of some sort. (File.renameTo()) seems to be the method recommended).

[Edit] The move operation in most (perhaps even... all) operating systems is much cheaper than a full copy and delete. It's equivalent to deleting the entry for the file in one directory and adding it to a different directory (or under a different name in the same directory). There's no need to touch the actual data in the file for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Java NIO:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/File2File.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `FileUtils` class from `org.apache.common`. Documentation [here](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own, you could use something like the apache commons IO utilities.

Here you could just call `FileUtils.copyFile`

see here for details
http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the [copyFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) method of the [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class from the [Apache commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) API.

It's been tested for you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do a file renameTo and give it the new location of the file as the parameter.

[See Here](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/440-how-move-file-another-directory.html)

Answer (score 0):

First try `File.renameTo()` to do a real move. If that fails, do a real copy/delete. Besides of this: `InputStream` and `OutputStream` is the most basic way to do the copy. But if you don't want to reinvent the wheel you can use [FileUtis](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) to do exactly what I have described.